# Subdomain on GCP for split domain routing

Tags: google-cloud-dns

How can I make a subdomain on google cloud platform for split domain routing? I already have an email provider on my domain so I want to do SDR to connect another email provider. My domain is registered from GoDaddy and then pointed to GCP where is hosted by Bitnami WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to create a [Split Domain Routing](https://luxsci.com/blog/split-domain-routing-getting-email-for-your-domain-at-two-providers.html) using GCP but you should know that Google Cloud is blocking the outbound connections on [ports 25, 465, and 587](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#using_standard_email_ports). 
So if you want to create an SDN you have to  set up your own email server on an instance using a non-standard ports and create the MX records in your DNS.

Comment: can you guide me to just make a subdomain on same IP address/instance

Comment: I'm not related with the DNS of GoDaddy, but you need to create a subdomain here you have a [link to the documentation](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-that-points-to-an-ip-address-4080) another option is use Google Cloud DNS, you only will need to change your NS records to point at the Google NS servers, then you can control your DNS zones directly with GCP.